# Design pattern - Client Server - Command pattern

Tags: c#, design-patterns, client-server, factory-pattern, command-pattern

I have a bunch of commands that I need to batch from the client and execute at the server. These commands are of different types and the contract for the command and the corresponding return types is shared between the client and server via a library.

Client side code is as follows-

```
var client = new ClientSDK();
client.Add(new Command1());
client.Add(new Command2());
client.Add(new Command3());

// Execute transmits all the commands to the server 
var results = client.Execute();
```

Server code -

```
List<CommandResult> Execute(List<CommandBase> commands)
{
   List<CommandResult>  results = new List<CommandResult>();
   foreach(CommandBase command in commands)
   {
       if(command.GetType == Command1)
       {
           results.Add(new Command1Executor(command).Execute())
       }
       else if(command.GetType == Command2)
       {
           results.Add(new Command1Executor(command).Execute())
       }
       else if(command.GetType == Command3)
       {
           results.Add(new Command3Executor(command).Execute())
       }    
       ..................     
   }
}
```

For each command there exists a unique execute function, that cannot be exposed as part of the client SDK. How do I make design changes such that I can get rid of the massive if/else block? There are tons of commands to be supported. I tried applying the command pattern as suggested here - [using the command and factory design patterns for executing queued jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8788366/using-the-command-and-factory-design-patterns-for-executing-queued-jobs) but this requires each command to implement the ICommand interface, which is not possible

Is there a better way to design this?

Comment: Put all command executors (or functons that create them) in a dictionary, keyed by command type. This way you won't need if else chain.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you need to map `CommandNExcecutor` type to `CommandN` type.

1) Use dictionary. This is easiest way:

```
private static readonly Dictionary<Type, Type> map = new Dictionary<Type, Type>
{
    {  typeof(Command1), typeof(Command1Executor) },
    {  typeof(Command2), typeof(Command2Executor) },
    ...
};

List<CommandResult> Execute(List<CommandBase> commands)
{
    return commands
        .Select(command =>
        {
            var executor = Activator.CreateInstance(map[command.GetType], command);
            return executor.Execute();
        })
        .ToList();
}
```

2) Use metadata (attributes). This fits plugin-based scenarios, when command types can be added dynamically, without rebuilding core functional. It could be your own implementation, or existing DI-container implementation (many of them expose metadata APIs).

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
public sealed class CommandExecutorAttribute : Attribute
{
    public CommandExecutorAttribute(Type commandType)
    {
        CommandType = commandType;
    }

    public Type CommandType { get; }

    // ...
}

[CommandExecutor(typeof(Command1))]
public sealed class Command1Executor : ICommandExecutor
{
    // ...
}

List<CommandResult> Execute(List<CommandBase> commands)
{
    return commands
        .Select(command =>
        {
            // obtain executor types somehow, e.g. using DI-container or
            // using reflection;
            // inspect custom attribute, which matches command type
            var executorType = ....

            var executor = Activator.CreateInstance(executorType , command);
            return executor.Execute();
        })
        .ToList();
}
```

**UPDATE**.

If you want to avoid reflection, in first case just replace type parameter for value in dictionary to `Func<CommandBase, ICommandExecutor>`:

```
private static readonly Dictionary<Type, Func<ICommandExecutor>> map = new Dictionary<Type, Func<ICommandExecutor>>
    {
        {  typeof(Command1), command => new Command1Executor(command) },
        {  typeof(Command2), command => new Command2Executor(command) },
        ...
    };
```

This will allow you to create executor through delegate instead of reflection:

```
var executor = map[command.GetType](command);
```

The second case can't *avoid* reflection completely, since you need to get executor types somehow. But it can be leaded to case 1 (with dictionary).

Make the lazy `map`:

```
private static readonly Lazy<Dictionary<Type, ConstructorInfo>> map = ...
```

Then, on `Lazy<T>` initialization, do all reflection work. Since this is `static Lazy<T>`, you will do this once per app domain. Calling `ConstructorInfo` is fast enough. Hence, you'll get performance hit only once, when handling first command.

Another options (they all assume `Lazy<Dictionary>`) for case 2 are:

- instead of reflecting `ConstructorInfo`, build `Expression<Func<CommandBase, ICommandExecutor>>`s using `ConstructorInfo`, compile them and put delegates into dictionary - this will be the same as delegates for case 1, but with dynamically supported command types;
- use DI-container, which emits IL to construct dependencies (AFAIK, [NInject](http://www.ninject.org/) does this);
- emit IL yourself (IMO, this will totally re-invent the wheel).

And finally, solve this the easiest way, *then* measure performance, *then* consider more complex way. Avoid premature optimization. I don't know anything about you commands nature, but I suspect, that command execution is *much* longer, than reflecting something (of course, there's a chance, that I'm wrong).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Definitely want to avoid Activator.CreateInstance and Reflection, as performance is priority.

Comment: @user1542794: actually, reflection isn't a main point in the answer. But I've updated it to give you some ideas how to speed up the code.

Comment: Thanks Dennis, your solution solves the problem quite cleanly.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the strategy pattern. A simple solution is below:

```
public class CommandStrategy 
{
    private static Dictionary<CommandTypes, Action<CommandStrategy>> strategy;

    public CommandStrategy()
    {
        strategy = new Dictionary<CommandTypes, Action<CommandStrategy>>();
        strategy.Add(CommandTypes.Command1, one => new Command1Executor().Execute());
        strategy.Add(CommandTypes.Command2, two => new Command2Executor().Execute());
        strategy.Add(CommandTypes.Command3, two => new Command3Executor().Execute());
    }

    public void Execute(CommandTypes type)
    {
        strategy[type].Invoke(this);
    }
}
```

The final execution might look like this:

```
CommandStrategy strategy = new CommandStrategy();

List<CommandBase> commands = new List<CommandBase>(){
                  new Command1(), new Command2(), new Command3() };

foreach (var item in commands)
{
   CommandTypes type = (CommandTypes)item;
   strategy.Execute(type);
}
```

Comment: I tried using the pattern, but I ran into other problems. Once I serialize the commands using NewtonSoft.Json libraries there are problems deserializing at the server side. Trying a couple of solutions, will keep you posted.